# Using Visual Studio Code and CMake to debug OpenGL (with GLEW&GLFW), unable to set breakpoints

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, cmake

I am trying to set up an application with glfw and glew to use OpenGL on Ubuntu18.04. I copied the glew example to the source file. With all the settings, I could run the application and see a white triangle on the screen. The problem is:

I can not enable breakpoints on the source code.
Once I starting to debug all the breakpoints I set became grep/disabled with comments "Unverified breakpoint".

I thought in the CMakeLists.txt, setting `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g -Wall")` could fix the issue, but it is not.

Any suggestions?

environment:
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
IDE: Visual Studio Code 1.33.1
cmake: 3.10.2
gdb: 8.2
gcc: 7.4

I set the launch.json as:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "MapPoints",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/MapPoints",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the case I need to change other settings I just post them all here
Here are my tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "cmake",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cmake",
            "args": [".."],
            "group": "build",            
        },
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "cmake",
            "args": ["--build", "."],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the CMakeLists.txt

```
#cmake --help-command-list
#cmake --help-variable-list
#cmake --help-property-list

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MapPoints)
SET(SOURCE main.cpp)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE})

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)

include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})

MESSAGE("project name: " ${PROJECT_NAME} )
MESSAGE("project src dir: " ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} )
FOREACH(item ${GLFW3_STATIC_LIBRARIES})
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  using lib: " ${item})
ENDFOREACH()

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
if (GLEW_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  [Found GLEW library]")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  GLEW include directory:" ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    FOREACH(item ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
        MESSAGE(STATUS "  using lib: " ${item})
    ENDFOREACH()

    include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
endif()

#link the local openGL driver library
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
if (OPENGL_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  [Found OpenGL library]")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  OpenGL include directory:" ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    FOREACH(item ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
        MESSAGE(STATUS "  using lib: " ${item})
    ENDFOREACH()

    include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g -Wall")
# using c++17
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

The source file is:

```
// sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev libglfw3
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.5f);
        glEnd();
        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to set your cmake build type to debug

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Alan's comments. It just missing set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug) in the CMakeLists.txt. Once the BUILD_TYPE is set, breakpoints are working as expected.